# Как вставить изображение из Excel в приложение C# на WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel

Пишу приложение которое использует данные из excel. Нужно в таблицу DataGridVew вставить кучу маленьких изображений. Как это сделать с помощью Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

```
     Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

     Excel.Application ObjWorkExcel = new Excel.Application();   
     Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook =  ObjWorkExcel.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\nevermind\tabl.xlsx"); 
     Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1]; 
//...
//  несколько строчек ненужного тут кода
//...
    BackgroundsDGV[0, i].Value = (Image)ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i + 3, j];
```

Comment: А вы что-то пытались уже сделать? Что именно не получается?

Comment: Код надо вставлять в сам пост, его можно отредактирвоать